# Get current screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There is any way to get the current screen?

I have my first (main) screen doing a bunch of things in background, like searching beacons. And every time I find one of my beacons I want to navigate to the screen that shows info about that beacon.

The problem is that, I'll keep pushing screens every time I get a new beacon found and I do not want that. If I'm in the detailScreen I want to replace the screen with the new data.

I want something like that:

```
if (navigation.currentScreen == 'Homepage' || navigation.currentScreen == 'Monument') {
   navigate('MonumentDetails', {monumento:i, poi:j, description_types:this.state.data.categories, data:this.state.data});
} else {
   replace('MonumentDetails', {monumento:i, poi:j, description_types:this.state.data.categories, data:this.state.data});
}
```

I know that there is no `navigation.currentScreen`, but is just to explain you what I want.

Hope you can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [navigate()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#navigate) with a key to keep only a single detail screen. Or you could replace the stack using [replace()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#replace)

```
navigate({
    routeName: 'MonumentDetails',
    params: {
        monumento:i,
        poi:j,
        description_types:this.state.data.categories, 
        data:this.state.data
    },
    key: 'detail',
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you provide a example with my navigate() with a key, please?

Comment: Thank you for the update, but that didn't work :/ It keep pushing multiple 'MonumentDetails' screen

Comment: Also, there is any way to define a key on the router, when I'm defining the screens available? Thks